# Symfony - "framework.test" config is not set to true

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

Using Symfony 5.2 and PhpUnit last version, I have this error with my functional test

```
LogicException: You cannot create the client used in functional tests if the "framework.test" config is not set to true.
```

Content of `config/packages/test/framework.yaml` :

```
framework:
    test: true
    session:
        storage_id: session.storage.mock_file
```

PHP part of my `phpunit.xml.dist` :

```
<php>
    <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1"/>
    <server name="APP_ENV" value="test" force="true"/>
    <server name="SHELL_VERBOSITY" value="-1"/>
    <env name="BOOTSTRAP_CLEAR_CACHE_ENV" value="test"/>
</php>
```

Here is the content of my Test :

```
class JWTTokenAuthenticatorTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function test_authentication_token()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $client->request(
            'POST',
            '/authentication_token',
            [],
            [],
            ['CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'],
            '{"email":"api@api.com","password":"api"}'
        );

        $this->assertResponseIsSuccessful();
        $this->assertMatchesRegularExpression('/{"token":"(.*)"}/i', $client->getResponse()->getContent());
    }
}
```

I have only default bootstrap.php file, I can't understand this error since the APP_ENV is well set to "test".

I tried to clear the cache.

When I dump `dd($_ENV['APP_ENV']);`, I have `dev`, I can't understand why.

Comment: Did you try changing `<server ... />` to `<env ... />`?

Comment: My god, sounds simple and nice

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/configuration.html#appendixes-configuration-php), `<server />` sets a variable in the super-global array `$_SERVER`.

For the `APP_ENV` you want to use `<env />` instead, it sets a variable in the `$_ENV` array.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add to config/packages/framework.yaml lines:

```
when@test:
   framework:
       test: true
       session:
           storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.mock_file
```