# You have requested a non-existent service "test.service_container". Did you mean this: "service_container"?

Tags: symfony, testing

PHPUnit 7.5.15 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException : You have requested a non-existent service "test.service_container". Did you mean this: "service_container"?
/opt/project/backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:277
/opt/project/backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:225
/opt/project/backend/tests/Functional/KernelAwareTest.php:49
/opt/project/backend/tests/Functional/FlightTaskManagement/AssignEmployeeToTaskTest.php:47

```
public function setUp(): void
    {
        global $kernel;

        $this->kernel = TestKernel::get();
        $kernel = $this->kernel;

        $container = $this->kernel->getContainer();

        if ($container === null)
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Container can not be null.');

        $this->container = $container->get('test.service_container');
        
//        $this->container = $container->get('service_container');
        
        /** @var Registry $doctrine */
        $doctrine = $this->container->get('doctrine');
        /** @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $manager */
        $manager = $doctrine->getManager();

        $this->entityManager = $manager;
        $this->entityManager->beginTransaction();

        if (!$this->container->initialized(WorkDistributionTransport::class)) {
            $this->container->set(WorkDistributionTransport::class, new InMemoryTransport());
        }
        if (!$this->container->initialized(Configuration::class)) {
            $this->container->set(Configuration::class, new TestConfiguration());
        }

        parent::setUp();
    }
```

It fails at line

```
$this->container = $container->get('test.service_container');
```

Symfony is 4.1 but looks like not finished to update. I can't remember by what we decided that it was not finished to update from earlier version.

Not clear if that is the problem that it is not finished to update. Looks like in 4.0 there is no such service so thats why. But then how to make it appear here?

Or maybe I can use

```
$this->container = $container->get('service_container');
```

as with earlier versions? Just what is faster way?

I just tried using

```
$this->container = $container->get('service_container');
```

but I then get

Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException : An exception occured while establishing a connection to figure out your platform version.
You can circumvent this by setting a 'server_version' configuration value

But I had set the version in config_test.yml so not clear which way is faster to fix.

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        server_version: 5.7
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     db_test
        port:     null
        dbname:   project
        user:     project
        password: project
```

Probably if I load service_container then it does not load test config and thats why I get this server_version error. So then need to somehow make it load test config.

Comment: Potential solution in the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67485873/13073160

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the "framework.test" config to "true":

`config/packages/test/framework.yaml`

```yaml
framework:
    test: true
```

Comment: Ideally, this should be the accepted solution @Darius.V

Answer (score 0):

Found: I had hardcoded dev environment in AppKernel. Probably thats why I was getting this error. Hardcoding test env fixed. Would be good somehow to make it without hardcoding, but it is still better than nothing:

```
public function __construct($environment, $debug)
    {
//        $environment ='dev';
        $environment ='test';
        $debug= true;

        parent::__construct($environment, $debug);
        date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a kernel creation.
The `$_ENV['APP_ENV']` value is 'dev' (mainly if composer generate test boostrap.php file).
You have to set `$_ENV['APP_ENV']` to 'test' (in bootstrap.php)  or use options:

```php
$kernel = self::bootKernel([
  "environment" => 'test'
]);
```

You see part of KernelTestCase:

```php
protected static function createKernel(array $options = []): KernelInterface
{
    static::$class ??= static::getKernelClass();

    if (isset($options['environment'])) {
        $env = $options['environment'];
    } elseif (isset($_ENV['APP_ENV'])) {
        $env = $_ENV['APP_ENV'];
    } elseif (isset($_SERVER['APP_ENV'])) {
        $env = $_SERVER['APP_ENV'];
    } else {
        $env = 'test';
    }

    if (isset($options['debug'])) {
        $debug = $options['debug'];
    } elseif (isset($_ENV['APP_DEBUG'])) {
        $debug = $_ENV['APP_DEBUG'];
    } elseif (isset($_SERVER['APP_DEBUG'])) {
        $debug = $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG'];
    } else {
        $debug = true;
    }

    return new static::$class($env, $debug);
}
```